# Is there a classification/group for UAVs with certain specs?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aircraft-classification

Is there a classification (like a name for UAVs that have max cruise velocity of 350km/hr) for UAVs please? So based on specs like range, velocity and altitude for example?

Thanks, any resources with classification would be appreciated too.

Comment: Regulatory?  What nation/s?

Comment: So more how to classify specs, so let’s say group or something to classify all UAVs that have a range of 500km and less for example

Comment: Be more specific about what you mean by "classification system", anyone could make up any arbitrary classification system they want based on those same performance numbers. That would not be a useful question and answer as it is unbounded. I am guessing you want to know about one of the following examples: legal certification, traffic control, engineering standards, industry sales categories. Please edit the question to narrow the focus of the question.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to certain specs? Not really.

Based on their roles they are loosely called MALE, HALE, UCAV, SUAS or whatever the manufacturer wishes to advertise them as. Since UAVs are fairly recent and a small part of aviation currently, legal classifications haven't been established yet.

If it helps have a look at 2021 notification by Government of India [here](https://www.dgca.gov.in/digigov-portal/?page=jsp/dgca/InventoryList/RegulationGuidance/Rules/The%20Unmanned%20Aircraft%20System%20Rules/Drones%20Rules%202021.pdf) which attempts to loosely classify them on weight